# Issue in using Cordova Media plugin

Tags: javascript, function, ionic-framework, media, cordova-plugins

I am developing an Android app using Ionic framework. In there I have used `Cordova Media Plugin` to play some mp3 files.

There is something strange happening in the code that I cannot understand. In the code I have a function to create a media object and play it as:

```
function playAudio(src) {
  myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
  myMedia.play();
  document.getElementById('forTest2').innerHTML = "end of playAudio";
}
```

In my JavaScript code I have this code section:

```
document.getElementById('forTest1').innerHTML = "before playAudio";
playAudio(audioSrc);
document.getElementById('forTest3').innerHTML = "visited after playAudio return";
```

I have added `document.getElementById` lines for debug.

When I run the code I see the following lines shown in the document screen:

```
before playAudio
end of playAudio
```

I expected after returning from the `playAudio` function to see these 3 lines instead of above 2 lines:

```
before playAudio
end of playAudio
visited after playAudio return
```

But I do not see the `visited after playAudio return` message, which shows we do not return from the `playAudio(audioSrc);`, which is strange.

Is there any explanation for this?

I am testing this on Android API 18 if it matters.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you have an element with id `forTest3`? because it makes no sense, that end of `playAudio` function is reached and then the next instruction isn't executed. It looks more like there is no element `forTest3`

Try to use `console.log()` instead.

```
function playAudio(src) {
  myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
  myMedia.play();
  console.log("end of playAudio");
}

console.log("before playAudio");
playAudio(audioSrc);
console.log("visited after playAudio return");
```

What happen if you add some additional outputs?

```
myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError, function(status){console.log(status)};
```

Comment: Yes I am sure I have an element with that Id. I am thinking there is something related to the Cordova media plugin.

Comment: But between forTest2 and forTest3 there is no instruction. I don't think that at this place some error occurs...

Comment: I know, is it possible that 'my Media.play()' somehow locks everything and just plays the audio?

Comment: @TJ1 Edited my answer